# Write / read xml file by two users simultaneously

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, html, wcf

I'm developing `WCF`-Service that is used by the `AJAX` calls.

I'm saving data to / take from `XML` files.

This does not seem a particularly good way for the reason that when two users simultaneously to access the service would **not be possible** to write / read the file **twice**.

My question is is there any way to also allow such a thing?

Or is better to keep a local copy of the file with users, to make it change there, then send it to service and replace it. (In this case also has a problem of exchanging two users simultaneously).

Can help with?

Comment: try using lock across the critical section of code where you are writing in the xml file. In this way only 1 user will have exclusive access to the resource and the other user will be in queue and will get access only when the 1st user is done with updating.

Comment: Check this link out as well. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/164428/C-FileStream-Lock-How-to-wait-for-a-file-to-get-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ConcurrencyModeAttribute instead of manually manage the lock.

When the service is configured with ConcurrencyMode.Single, WCF will provide automatic
synchronization to the service context and disallow concurrent calls.

If there are concurrent callers they will placed in a queue and served in FIFO order.

Remember this could be overkill if you have significantly more read operations than write.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx